# Sphinx: autodoc не парсит, ошибок не выдаёт

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Есть файл test.py

```
'''
the doc for all file
'''

def one():
    '''
    The documentation ONE
    '''
    pass

class two:
    '''
    Docs for two
    '''
    def three():
        '''
        docs for three
        '''
        pass
    def foure():
        '''
        dost for foure
        '''
        pass
```

рядом с ним файл test.rst

```
===============
automodule
===============
autogenerate

.. automodule:: test
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

в cmd пишу : sphinx-quickstart
(выбирал разделять и не разделять папки ресурсов и билда)
меняю conf.py на

```
...
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',  # Core library for html generation from docstrings
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary',  # Create neat summary tables
]
...
```

в цмд пишу : make html
всё билдится без ошибок (не считая отсутствия ссылки на test), открываю в браузере test.html и вижу отсутствие автодокументации. Однако при использовании 'sphinx-autobuild . folder' всё генерируется.
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Суть ошибки заключалась в неверных путях:
В файле conf.py следует указать путь к текущей папке (точнее к папке с модулем для которого и составляем документацию)

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '.'))
```